# Copy to variable range

Tags: variables, google-sheets, copy, range, paste

**I have this code**

```
function ArchiveData() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1TDFUBUnW...'); // sss = spreadsheet
  var source = sss.getRange('Code!D5:F78'); // source = source sheet
  //copy to target
    var cnumber = sss.getSheetByName("Code").getRange('F3').getValue; // Column number
    source.copyTo(sss.getSheetByName("S-28").getRange(5,cnumber), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

**ERROR:** Keeps returning error in the last line of code. It works when I put a number instead of using the class cnumber.

In cell 'Code!F3' I would like to specify which is the target column number. This is a variable specified by what month the user selected. For example, for **September** the cnumber class returns: 3, for **October** it's 7, **November** is 11, **December** is 15, **January** is 19, **February** is 23, March is 27, and so on ... all the way to August.

So, my goal is ultimately to tell the script where to paste the copied values. However, the column where it needs to paste varies on the selected month.

Comment: this line code is strange: `var rownumber = shcl.getRange('Code!F3').getValues`. Try using `getValue()` instead. And this code is incorrect: `tss.getRange('S-28!'&rownumber)`, change it to `tss.getRange('S-28!' + rownumber)`.

Comment: Thank you . It works very well!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

this line code is strange:

```
var rownumber = shcl.getRange('Code!F3').getValues.
```

Try using `getValue()` instead.

And this code is incorrect:

```
tss.getRange('S-28!'&rownumber)
```

change it to `tss.getRange('S-28!' + rownumber)`